# When required to re-encode video multiple times, is it wisest to use fastest preset until very last re-encode?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-editing, video-encoding

If a video requires re-encoding it multiple times with `ffmpeg` because it needs multiple changes done to it such as crop, resize, convert, compile (concat), convert again, etc... then wouldn't it be wisest to use an encoding preset such as `ultrafast` during all of the re-encodes until the very last re-encode, and then use something like `slow` or `veryslow` ?

Doing this is the exact same as re-encoding on `slow` or `veryslow` the entire time, the only difference is one wastes my time and the other makes efficient use of my time. Do I have this right?

Or would doing this lose quality?

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong.

*Every* stage at encoding using a "fast" preset will loose more quality than the same pass run at a slow preset. The loss at each stage will be cumulative to the point the there will be some (potentially significant) difference between your method and a full run with slower presets.

The problem is known as [generation loss](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss). As you run each generation at lower quality (faster preset) you will loose more data per generation. The file sizes might be similar in the final slow stage, especially if you use a quality based setting, but all that means is that it is trying harder to be more "faithful" to the input it is given. It is effectively trying harder to reproduce noise and quality loss introduced at earlier stages.

If you are doing multiple stage conversions then you would be much better off, in terms of both speed and quality, converting to an uncompressed output from the first stage, doing all your processing on the uncompressed video and then doing a final compression stage.

Otherwise you should try and do as many steps of video conversion in one run of the program as possible. I believe that `ffmpeg` can chain cropping, resizing and conversion into one step so that you only incur a single step of generation loss.

The size of the file being the same or similar means nearly nothing, you already threw away more visual fidelity in the earlier runs and it cannot be recovered.

Comment: There are lossless compressed video formats that do not create such unwieldy, behemoth files as uncompressed does. See ffv1, utvideo, lossless H.264 (using `-crf 0` with x264), etc.